# Is there a tool to parse C++ that enforces documentation

Tags: c++, documentation

Is there a tool that automatically detects if all the functions defined in the header file are documented?

Comment: I want a tool that verifies that the documentation is correct!

Comment: Well, my goal was to scan a header file and obtain the set of functions that were not documented. Doxygen does it nicely enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use doxygen's [`WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_warn_if_undocumented) option.